# JdbcPollingChannelAdapter update using only the id -- no bean

Tags: spring, spring-integration, integration

I have the following bean definition:

```
@Bean
JdbcPollingChannelAdapter jdbcPollingChannelAdapter() {
    // Get all the pending jobs
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(jdbcTemplate, "select id from poller_jobs where status = 'PENDING'");
    // Immediately mark them as running so the next jdbc poll doesn't re-process them
    adapter.setUpdateSql("update poller_jobs set status='RUNNING' where id in (:id)");
    adapter.setMaxRowsPerPoll(100);
    adapter.setRowMapper((r, i) -> r.getLong("id"));
    return adapter;
}
```

And this fails because the row mapper maps to just a `long` id and so the adapter doesn't know how to grab the ID that I need in the update.  Anyone know how to do that without needing to `select *` and map to a full object?  That seems like more overhead than I really need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<inbound-channel-adapter data-source="dataSource"
                             channel="target"
                             query="select id from item where status=2"
                             update="update item set status=10 where id in (:#root)"
                             update-per-row="true"
                             row-mapper="columnRowMapper"/>

    <beans:bean id="columnRowMapper" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SingleColumnRowMapper"/>
```

So, the first is `(:#root)` as param placeholder just because the default `setUpdateSqlParameterSourceFactory()` is `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory`, where the root object of evaluation context is the result of `SELECT` or, as it is stand by the `update-per-row="true"`, each row in the `ResultSet`:

```
 if (payload != null && this.updateSql != null) {
        if (this.updatePerRow) {
            for (Object row : payload) {
                executeUpdateQuery(row);
            }
        }
        else {
            executeUpdateQuery(payload);
        }
    }
```

Therefore what you need in your configuration is this two lines of code:

```
 adapter.setUpdateSql("update poller_jobs set status='RUNNING' where id in (:#root)");
 adapter.setUpdatePerRow(true);
```

The `SingleColumnRowMapper` does the trick for really single column in the `ResultSet`, BTW.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!